# UI thread sleeping even though postInvalidate() has been called to trigger onDraw()

Tags: android, user-interface, sleep, invalidation

I have a problem with `postInvalidate` with my view. I have a thread called `MainFormViewRefresh` that wakes up periodically and only calls the `postInvalidate()` method for my view. This should wake the `main` UI thread and eventually call the view's `onDraw()` method and have it redrawn, but the main thread is just sleeping long times even when `postInvalidate()` is called.

The UI thread is blocked on `MessageQueue#nativePollOnce` and it doesn't wake up from `postInvalidate()`. Why is it sleeping even when it has things to do? Is it missing my `postInvalidate()` calls? My understanding is that the `postInvalidate` should put an event in the queue and wake up the UI thread blocking on `nativePollOnce`. The CPU is only up to 50% because it is sleeping about half of the time.

The picture illustrates the problem. Each spike of activity on MainFormViewRefresh ends with a call to `postInvalidate()`. The periods of inactivity in the main thread is time its spends blocked in `MessageQueue#nativePollOnce`. As can be seen, `postInvalidate()` is called several times without waking the main thread.

The main period of activity on the `main` thread is `onDraw()` (blue).

[image: View of running threads]

Comment: after update my prev comment is still valid. blind guessing: you are using some long running stuff on UI/main thread ... example: `onClick(...) { while(true) { /*some other stuff*/ postInvalidate(); } }` <= postInvalidate will "not works" since you are on main thread already using thread like this will not work either pseudo code `onClick(...) {  var thread = new Thread(run=>while(true) { /*some other stuff*/ postInvalidate(); }); thread.join() }`

Comment: It seems however that the UI thread is sleeping and thus not running anything at all.

Comment: maybe you doing too much stuff in `onDraw` ... main thread is waiting until `onDraw`(since onDraw is called on main thread) is finished and do not "pick invalidate event"

Comment: `onDraw` takes 20 ms to perform but only returns to `onDraw` again after about 60ms. The other 40ms it does somehing else, sleeps it seems.